# Is there already some std::vector based set/map implementation?

Tags: c++, optimization

For small sets or maps, it's usually much faster to just use a sorted vector, instead of the tree-based `set`/`map` - especially for something like 5-10 elements. LLVM has some classes [in that spirit](http://llvm.org/docs/ProgrammersManual.html#ds_sequential), but no real adapter that would provide a `std::map` like interface backed up with a `std::vector`.

Any (free) implementation of this out there?

**Edit**: Thanks for all the alternative ideas, but I'm really interested in a vector based set/map. I do have specific cases where I tend to create huge amounts of sets/maps which contain usually less than 10 elements, and I do really want to have less memory pressure. Think about for example neighbor edges for a vertex in a triangle mesh, you easily wind up with 100k sets of 3-4 elements each.

Comment: I've never experienced performance problems with std::sets or maps of 5 or 10 elements... I don't think you will notice anything. Are you creating more than one million of very small std::set's?

Comment: Yeah, possibly, the more important problem I face is that each set allocates lots of nodes, which I want to avoid.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just stumbled upon your question, hope its not too late.

I recommend a great (open source) library named [Loki](http://loki-lib.sourceforge.net/).
It has a vector based implementation of an associative container that is a drop-in replacement for std::map, called [AssocVector](https://github.com/snaewe/loki-lib/blob/master/include/loki/AssocVector.h).

It offers better performance for accessing elements (and worst performance for insertions/deletions).

The library was written by [Andrei Alexandrescu](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andrei_Alexandrescu) author of [Modern C++ Design](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modern_C%2B%2B_Design).

It also contains some other really nifty stuff.

Comment: Has that been maintained over the years?

Answer (score 4):

If you can't find anything suitable, I would just wrap a std::vector to do sort() on insert, and implement find() using lower_bound().  It should be straight forward, and just as efficient as a custom solution.

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly what I'm planning, but I hoped for some code out there to save me from this ;)

Comment: Why is it not enough to just perform an "insert into sorted array" operation when adding an element? i.e. use `lower_bound()` then, as well; and move all of the data afterwards by 1 forward?

Comment: Also, this will not be as efficient as a custom solution. Consider a custom solution which keeps most of the data in a vector but maintains an auxiliary vector of recently-inserted elements (by order of insertion), that is searched from the most to the least recent. Now suppose the access pattern is "insert x, delete x, insert x, delete x" n times. The custom solution will take O(n) time - and with a good constant too - while the solution you suggested will taken O(n^2) time, and thrash the cash IIANM.

Answer (score 4):

Old post, I know, but for more recent visitors, Boost's flat_set and flat_map look like what you need. See https://theboostcpplibraries.com/boost.container for more information.

Answer (score 3):

If the set or map truly is small, the performance gained by micro-optimizing the data structure will have little to no noticeable effects. You'll save maybe one or two memory (read: cache) lookups when searching a tiny tree vs tiny vector, which in the big picture is insignificant.

Having said that, you could give hash_map a try. Lookups by key are guaranteed to run in constant time.

Comment: Old post, but I got here from a legitimate google search, So I feel the need to chime in. Except if, as the OP mentioned, he is using thousands of them, then it is not *necessarily* micro optimization anymore. There could be noticeable differences do to the improved cache locality and reduced indirection of a vector.

Comment: The thing is, there might be many many copies of the small set or map.

Comment: Also, @Marcin, I believe you're wrong about the noticeable effect, since OP might save uncached accesses.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know any such implementation, but there are some functions that help working with sorted vectors already in STL, such as [`lower_bound`](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/lower_bound.html) and [`upper_bound`](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/upper_bound.html).

Comment: Yeah, I know, it's not that difficult to implement, but before wasting time, I'd rather use some off-the-shelf-solution.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you're looking for unordered map's and unordered set's. Try taking a look at the TR1 unordered containers that rely on hashing, or the [Boost.Unordered](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/doc/html/unordered.html) container library. Underneath the interface, I'm not sure if they really do use std::vector, but I'd wager it's worth taking a look at.