# Pairwise iteration over a vector

Tags: c++, stl, vector, iterator, containers

### Question Synopsis

Given a `std::vector<T>`, how can I create a *view* that exposes the interface of a `std::vector<std::pair<T, T>>`, where each pair consists of two consecutive elements in the underlying vector?

### Details

The goal is to create multiple container abstractions over the same storage, which is a `std::vector<T>`. The type `T` is some sort of discriminated union, à la [Boost Variant](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/variant.html). The storage requirement is given, otherwise I would simply use a `std::vector<std::pair<T, T>>`. The views over the storage I would like to support are sets (unique elements) and tables (associative array, unique keys). While the former is straight-forward by ensuring the set uniqueness property, the latter requires handling keys and values.

To support associative array semantics over a `std::vector<T>`, I am currently thinking that the best way would be to create a view of the form `std::vector<std::pair<T, T>>`, and that this view would allow me use STL algorithms to maintain the required properties. Does this sound like a good strategy? Are there any other ideas?

### Related

If I had an iterator *i* that goes over every even element and iterator *j* that goes through every odd element, Boost's [zip iterator](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/iterator/doc/zip_iterator.html) comes to mind, which would enable iteration in *(i,j)* pairs. But my use case is slightly different in that I do not have two separate containers.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by a *view*. How about a `vector` of `pair` of iterators into the `vector<T>`? Or a custom class in place of `pair<...>` which maintains a single iterator into the `vector<T>` and sometimes makes a copy of that iterator and increments it?

Comment: Should be pretty trivial to implement in terms of [`boost::iterator_facade`](http://www.boost.org/libs/iterator/doc/iterator_facade.html).

Comment: The initial part of the question seems to suggest that you could simply define your own `iterator` class. It would contain an ordinary `vector::const_iterator` as member and define `operator*` such that it returns a pair, and `operator++` such that it increments the inner iterator twice. But I don't understand how that enables you to provide an associative-array "view" of the vector. The pairwise elements will still be in the original order. There will be no notion of deduplication or mapping.

Comment: After reading again, I realized you apparently somehow ensure that the consecutive pairs stored in the vector are such they could be the entries of an associative array. I.e. the first element of every pair is unique, etc. In that case: Is the only thing you need the iterator? Or do you also need functions that search for a key and return a value, insert a new pair etc? In other words, are you looking to implement a `vector`-based class that implements the full interface of a `map`?

Comment: @jogojapan: Yes, I am essentially implementing a `map` on top of a `vector<T>`, however, not on top of a `vector<pair<T,T>>`. It seems that all I need for that is to define a custom iterator?!

Comment: Well, for a full implementation of the map interface you'd need `find()`, `insert()` etc. as well, right? I don't know any existing library that does this on the basis of a `std::vector`. There is a similar problem discussed in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/449940/777186), and the [`AssocVector`](http://loki-lib.sourceforge.net/html/a00645.html) from a library called Loki they mention is similar to what you want. (But it's also different, because it uses a vector of pairs, not of single elements as in your case).

Comment: True, I would need to implement `find()` and friends. You're getting ahead of me :-). Implementing these functions won't be difficult once I can use the STL via iterators. I am aware of Loki's `AssocVector` and it's exactly the model I have in mind. But before that, I need to have a notion of key-value pairs on top of the basic vector. It looks like the `iterator_facade` is a nice way to achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that Boost's `iterator_facade` is indeed what I want. Here is a toy example (with rough edges):

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <boost/iterator/iterator_facade.hpp>

template <typename Value>
class pair_iterator
  : public boost::iterator_facade<
        pair_iterator<Value>
      , Value
      , boost::random_access_traversal_tag
      , std::pair<Value&, Value&>
      , typename std::vector<Value>::difference_type
    >
{
public:
    typedef std::vector<Value> vector_type;
    typedef typename vector_type::difference_type difference_type;
    typedef typename vector_type::iterator iterator;

    pair_iterator()
        : i_(0)
    {
    }

    explicit pair_iterator(iterator i)
      : i_(i)
    {
    }

private:
    friend class boost::iterator_core_access;

    bool equal(pair_iterator<Value> const& other) const
    {
        return i_ == other.i_;
    }

    void increment()
    {
        ++i_;
        ++i_;
    }

    std::pair<Value&, Value&> dereference() const
    {
        return { std::ref(*i_), std::ref(*(i_ + 1)) };
    }

    void advance(difference_type n)
    {
        i_ += n << 1;
    }

    difference_type distance_to(pair_iterator<Value> const& other) const
    {
        return other.i_ - i_;
    }

    iterator i_;
};

int main()
{
    typedef pair_iterator<int> int_map_iterator;
    std::vector<int> v{2, 20, 3, 30, 5, 50, 7, 70};
    int_map_iterator first(v.begin());
    int_map_iterator last(v.end());

    std::for_each(first + 1, last,
                  [](std::pair<int&, int&> p)
                  {
                      std::cout
                          << p.first << " -> "
                          << p.second << std::endl;
                  });

    return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
3 -> 30
5 -> 50
7 -> 70
```

### Issues

- Conversion from `iterator` to `const_iterator` has not yet been addressed by this example.
- The iterator only works when the underlying vector has even size and needs a more conservative implementation of `dereference()`.

Comment: This looks like it crashes when the vector size is odd.

Comment: That's correct, thanks for pointing it out. One could check for `size % 2` in the iterator constructor or use a safer dereference operator.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing to note is that you won't be able to expose a `std::pair<T const, T>&` as a means to modify the objects. What may be sufficantly close, however, is a `std::pair<T const, T&>` as you'll only be able to change the second part.

With this out of the way it seems you need

1. An iterator type which skips every other value and is used to iterate over the keys (elements with even indices) and the values (elements with odd indices).
2. Something like a "zip iterator" which takes two iterators and exposes a `std::pair<T const, T&>` obtained from them.

Comment: Would you mind elaborating on the need for `std::pair<T const, T&>`? Is this a requirement for `map`-like containers?

Comment: Well, you want to be able to  change the value using something like `it->second = ...` whole the key is immutable. Similarily, something like `m[key]` should probably work.

Comment: I see. Would it suffice to provide `std::pair<T const&, T&>`, i.e., taking the key by reference as well?

Comment: Yes, I think this should be fine: you don't want to copy the key either. The "normal" maps return a `std::pair<Key const, Value>&` which you won't gave. It is just attempting to give it compatible access.